# How to return different types on multiple child classes?

Tags: c#

I've read some questions related to my problem but I've found them pretty specific to certain program design so I'm hoping to get some advice on my own specific case...

I am working on a program which allows you to do logic operations based on a node graph, you have different types of nodes, for example; CostantNode and Addition node, you can draw two Constants and link them to the Addition node so this last will Process the inputs and throw a result. So far Node class has a Virtual method for processing:

```
//Node Logic
    public virtual float Process(Dictionary<Guid, Node> allNodes)
    {
        //Override logic on child nodes.
        return Value;
    }
```

This method its overrided on each derivated nodeType, in Addition for example:

```
        /// <summary>
    /// We pass Allnodes in so the Node doesnt need any static reference to all the nodes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="allNodes"></param>
    /// <returns>Addition result (float)</returns>
    public override float Process(Dictionary<Guid, Node> allNodes)
    {
        //We concatenate the different input values in here:
        float Result = 0;

        if (Input.Count >= 2)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Input.Count; i++)
            {
                var _floatValue = allNodes[Input[i].TailNodeGuid].Value;
                Result += _floatValue;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Log: " + this.Name + "|| Processed an operation with " + Input.Count + " input elements the result was " + Result);

            this.Value = Result;
            // Return the result, so DrawableNode which called this Process(), can update its display label
            return Result;
        }
        return 0f;
    }
```

So far, everything worked great until I tried to implement an Hysteris node, which basically should evaluate an input and return TRUE or FALSE, this is were Im stuck since I need to return a Boolean and not a float value, I made it work by parsing the return to Bool on the View side of the program but I want to be able to customize Process() return types in specific child Nodes, also, nodes store the result of process in a float variable called Value which also in Hysteris I would need the value of the node to be True or False...

Hopefully you guys can provide me with some guidance on how to approach this issue, I haven't worked deeply with POO.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, you could return `System.Object` and use typecasting...

Comment: The first thing I thought when I read this question: "This guy is facing some serious design issues...". Maybe you should learn about the Liskov substitution principle.

Comment: @Iker: Why would you want to return either a `bool` or a `float` from the same virtual method? What would the calling code do with a `bool` value when it's all set up to process a `float` value? You either need two separate methods (in which case there is no need for polymorphism), or you need to re-think your whole design.

Comment: @Christian Hayter
Small video to give an idea of how the program work...
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bp24W3ebwAQ&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# has no concept of polymorphic return values.  You'll have to either return a structure containing both values:

```
struct ProcessResult
{
    public float Value;
    public bool Hysteresis;
}

ProcessResult Process(Dictionary<Guid, Node> allNodes)
{
    var result = new ProcessResult();
    // Assign value to result.Value
    // Assign hysteresis to result.Hysteresis
    // return result
}
```

or us a pattern similar to the Framework's TryParse pattern:

```
bool TryProcess(Dictionary<Guid, Node> allNodes, out float result)
{
    // Assign value to result
    // Return hysteresis
}
```